# Too Long Procedure

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the part of my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(7, Target.Column), Cells(505, Target.Column))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(7, Target.Column), Cells(505, Target.Column)), Target) > 1 Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    MsgBox "DUBLICATED PLEASE DEFINE ANOTHER!"

End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H7")) Is Nothing Then Range("K7").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H8")) Is Nothing Then Range("K8").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H9")) Is Nothing Then Range("K9").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H10")) Is Nothing Then Range("K10").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H11")) Is Nothing Then Range("K11").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H12")) Is Nothing Then Range("K12").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H13")) Is Nothing Then Range("K13").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H14")) Is Nothing Then Range("K14").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H15")) Is Nothing Then Range("K15").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H16")) Is Nothing Then Range("K16").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H17")) Is Nothing Then Range("K17").ClearContents    
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H18")) Is Nothing Then Range("K18").ClearContents    
'Next 500 rows

End Sub
```

The codes continue down 500 rows and check each rows even work for 50 lines but give Error of "Procedure is Too Long" for 500 rows

Is it a way to shorten the procedure agains the Error code?

---

**EDIT** (from comments below)

Some of cells are merged and the changed code pasted below has tested with error of "can not change part of merged cell" (G:J):

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H7:J55")) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "K").ClearContents 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("T11:T17")) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "U").ClearContents 
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E61:E109")) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "G:J").ClearContents 
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Highly repetitious code is a code-smell (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell ). 500 nearly identical lines should be refactored so as to be 1 line in the body of a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the other ~470 lines of code it's impossible to capture all of your conditions (and TBH you'll need to completely re-write the event handler anyway), but in general you'll want to approach this type of problem by looking for conditions that you are repeating, and then code against *only what differs*.  For example, in these lines of code...

> ```
> If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H7")) Is Nothing Then Range("K7").ClearContents
> If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H8")) Is Nothing Then Range("K8").ClearContents
> If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H9")) Is Nothing Then Range("K9").ClearContents
> If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H10")) Is Nothing Then Range("K10").ClearContents
> 'Etc...
> ```

...the only thing that is changing is the row number. Everything else is identical. So test for and change the *column* - it's the same for all of them:

```
If Target.Column = 8 Then
    Cells(Target.Row, 11).ClearContents
End If
```

Note how that isolates the similarity and works with only the difference. Keep in mind that this is not going to be a "copy from SO, paste into VBE" solution - you'll need to add additional constraints based on your comment about merged cells.

---

There is also no reason to use `Intersect` for individual cells. Testing the `Row` and `Column` is much, much more efficient and easier to read. The only way that `Range("H7")` is going to intersect with a single cell is if that cell is `"H7"`.

---

You can also apply the same sort of logic in the `If` statement above to your guard clauses at the top of the procedure here:

> ```
> If Intersect(Target, Range(Cells(7, Target.Column), Cells(505, Target.Column))) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
>
> If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
> ```

The first check tests to see if the row is between 7 and 505 - that's it. The second constraint is to only operate on single cells.  As a side note this is a bug, as it ignores the fact that the user can bypass ***all of your validation*** by deleting or pasting multiple cells - you'll need to tackle that problem after you re-write the rest of it. If you reverse the order, you can simply test the `.Row` like this:

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row < 7 Or Target.Row > 505 Then Exit Sub
```

---

From the code in your comment, this is a bug:

> ```
> Cells(Target.Row, "G:J").ClearContents
> ```

`Cells` expects a *single* column.  Passing "G:J" will be an error 1004. If you need to operation on multiple columns, you have to use `Range`:

```
Range(Cells(Target.Row, 7), Cells(Target.Row, 10)).ClearContents
```

I'm guessing from the comment about merged cells that you don't need to operate a `Range` in that particular case anyway. If the cells are merged, you need to use the top left cell in the merged range. So for example, if "G10:J10" is a merged range of cells and `Target.Row` was 10, you would clear it with:

```
Cells(Target.Row, 7).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. The last version is pasted in my next comment; but still 2 codes referenced Column = 8 & Column = 13 work versa (I mean I need to delete next rows when delete source row but this deletes when I type the source cell), other 2 works fine. However cells on column 8 is merged to column 10 & cells on column 13 merged to column 17.

Comment: Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Target.Row < 7 Or Target.Row > 505 Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(7, target.Column), Cells(505, target.Column)), target) > 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Undo
    
    MsgBox "DUBLICATED PLEASE DEFINE ANOTHER!"
End If

Comment: If target.Column = 8 Then
    Cells(target.Row, 11).ClearContents
End If

If target.Column = 13 Then
    Cells(target.Row, 18).ClearContents
End If

If target.Column = 20 Then
    Cells(target.Row, 21).ClearContents
End If

If target.Column = 5 Then
    Range(Cells(target.Row, 7), Cells(target.Row, 10)).ClearContents
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Don't think 500 lines could cause that error, but you can replace the second bit with this

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H7:H18")) Is Nothing Then Target.Offset(, 3).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

The middle to end section:

- needs to wrap `Application.EnableEvents = False` around your last test as well
- your last test should be `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H7:H505")) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "K").ClearContents`

*new section*

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(7, Target.Column), Cells(505, Target.Column)), Target) > 1 Then
    Application.Undo
    MsgBox "DUPLICATED PLEASE DEFINE ANOTHER!"
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H7:H505")) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "K").ClearContents
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Thanks for yor reply. Now changed the codes as yours:

Comment: I have 2 problems now:
1- Working reverse. (Clearing row while entering a value to dependant cell)
2- Some of cells are merged and the changed code pasted below has tested with error of "can not change part of merged cell" (G:J)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H7:J55")) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "K").ClearContents

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("T11:T17")) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "U").ClearContents

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E61:E109")) Is Nothing Then Cells(Target.Row, "G:J").ClearContents

Application.EnableEvents = True